Appium not find text that is seperated in two lines
Have a good day.
I have an issue while searching for text in appium, the issue is that I am searching for the text "Send Gifts" by using following xpath
//*[@text = 'Send Gifts']

but katalon kannot find related text, note the text is displayed in two lines
in the actual screen
"Send
Gift"

But when open appium inspector I find it in one line as displayed in attachment.
Another note I have tried to reach another text that has only one line of text, and appium find text successfully.
Send Gift option
try to find item in appium

Try this //*[contains(@text, 'Send Gifts')] or this //*[contains(@text, 'Gifts')] or this //*[contains(@text, 'Send')]

When dealing with multi-line text elements in mobile automation testing, particularly with tools like Appium, it's important to consider how the text is actually rendered and recognized by the automation framework. The issue you're facing, where "Send Gifts" is shown as "Send\nGifts" (in two lines) on the screen but appears in a single line in the Appium inspector, can be tricky.
Here are a few approaches and considerations to help you solve this problem:

Use Contains XPath Function
If the text is broken into two lines, using the exact match in XPath might not work as expected. You could use the contains() function in your XPath to match parts of the text. However, this approach might match other elements that you're not interested in. It's a bit of a trade-off but can be useful in some cases:

xpath
//*[contains(@text, 'Send') and contains(@text, 'Gifts')]


Use Accessibility ID or Resource ID
Whenever possible, prefer using accessibility IDs or resource IDs over text matches. These IDs are less likely to change than the UI text and are not affected by how the text is displayed (single line, multi-line, etc.):

java
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("id_of_the_element");
// or
driver.findElementById("resource_id_of_the_element");


Regular Expressions in XPath
XPath 1.0 (which is commonly supported) does not have native support for regular expressions, making it tricky to match texts that span multiple lines or have variable parts. Some frameworks or tools may offer extensions or workarounds, but these are not universally supported and might not work with Appium/Katalon.

Use UIAutomator2 Strategy (for Android)
If you're testing an Android app, you can switch to using UIAutomator2, which has a more flexible query syntax and might handle multi-line texts better:


java
driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new 
UiSelector().textContains(\"Send\").textContains(\"Gifts\")"));


Adjust Your Test or App (if possible)
Sometimes, the easiest path is to adjust either the test or the app (if you have the ability to request changes). For example, ensuring that texts used for critical elements are displayed in a consistent manner that's friendly to automation can save a lot of headaches.

Capture the Whole Screen Text and Analyze
As a last resort or in very complex scenarios, you could capture the entire screen's text (using something like an OCR tool or a dump of all visible texts) and then search through that text in your test script. This is more complex and potentially slower but can be used when other methods fail.


Closing Note
Automating UI tests for apps that have dynamic or complex layouts can be challenging. Sometimes, combining several strategies or finding creative workarounds is necessary. Always keep in mind the balance between making your tests robust and not overly complex.
